# Entity field type checkbox required

Tags: symfony

i don´t know why my entity field type (with checkboxes) not validate as required. May be I am doing something wrong?

```
$builder   ...
...
->add('idiomas', 'entity', 
   array('class' => 'BackendIdiomasBundle:Idioma',
   'expanded' => true,
   'multiple' => true,'required' => true))
```

This is an entity field type with checkboxes (*'expanded' => true,'multiple' => true*), but i need at least one of entity values must be checked before the form is sent. For this I set to 'required'=> true, but It doesn´t work!!!

Any idea or clue?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using validation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

```
Your\MainBundle\Entity\Whatever:
    properties:
        idiomas:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - NotNull: ~
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I did try it in annotations. Also It doesn´t work /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EscuelaIdioma", mappedBy="escuela", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
    * @Assert\NotBlank()
    * @Assert\NotNull()
    */
    protected $idiomas;